# MySQL Similar 2 Columns need begining data by 1st column

Tags: php, mysql, regex, where-clause

```
$genre = 'Action|Adventure|Crime';
$starcast= 'Tom Hanks|Felicity Jones|Omar Sy|Irrfan Khan';

$S2 = mysql_query("SELECT title,hash,year FROM IMDB WHERE starcast REGEXP '".$starcast."' or genre REGEXP '".$genre."' LIMIT 16") or die (mysql_error());
        while ($S = mysql_fetch_assoc($S2)){
```

this is working but results are in mixed data.

data LIMIT is 16.

i want 1st all data by starcast.

Example :- If startcast data match with 9 result so last 7 data needed match with genre.

sorry for bad English.

Question is UPDATE.....

Comment: Do not use the `mysql_*` API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt how your posted query works. It should throw compilation error. Your query should look like

```
SELECT title,hash,year 
FROM IMDB WHERE starcast REGEXP '".$starcast."' or genre REGEXP '".$genre."' 
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 16
```

*If startcast data match with 9 result so last 7 data needed match with genre*

don't think you can make it like that unless you use `UNION` query like

```
(SELECT title,hash,year 
FROM IMDB WHERE starcast REGEXP '".$starcast."' 
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 9)
 UNION
(SELECT title,hash,year 
FROM IMDB WHERE genre REGEXP '".$genre."'
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 7 )
```

Comment: It need not be since you are passing it parameter. First try out the suggested answer. If doesn't work then comment. else edit your post and include sample data and desired output.

Comment: now is working very well but issue is results LIMIT number.

if starcast results is 16 so ignore genre ... or if starcast results is 14 so i need 2 results from Genre...????

Comment: @HiteshAghara, nope .. you can't do it that way. Probably you will have to have that logic in your application end.

Comment: Hey Rahul @  Now is working perfect for me ... simple change.........
(SELECT title,hash,year 
FROM IMDB WHERE starcast REGEXP '".$starcast."')
 UNION
(SELECT title,hash,year 
FROM IMDB WHERE genre REGEXP '".$genre."') LIMIT 16

Comment: `UNION` may speed up the query for `= ' ...'` if the column is indexed.  But it won't help `REGEXP`.